exec: "vmware": executable file not found in $PATH error using WSL2
I'm running Ubuntu 20 inside the WSL2 on Windows 11. VMWare Workstation Pro installed with license.
I run packer build and get this error
Build 'vmware-vmx' errored after 48 milliseconds 826 microseconds: Failed creating VMware driver: Unable to initialize any driver for this platform. The errors
from each driver are shown below. Please fix at least one driver
to continue:
* exec: "vmware": executable file not found in $PATH
* exec: "vmware": executable file not found in $PATH
* exec: "vmplayer": executable file not found in $PATH
* exec: "vmplayer": executable file not found in $PATH


==> Wait completed after 48 milliseconds 874 microseconds

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> vmware-vmx: Failed creating VMware driver: Unable to initialize any driver for this platform. The errors
from each driver are shown below. Please fix at least one driver
to continue:
* exec: "vmware": executable file not found in $PATH
* exec: "vmware": executable file not found in $PATH
* exec: "vmplayer": executable file not found in $PATH
* exec: "vmplayer": executable file not found in $PATH


==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.

This is my builder block from packer.json file
"builders": [
        {
            "type": "vmware-vmx",
            "source_path": "vmwareExportBase/vmx/ubuntu_hardening_22.vmx",
            "format": "ova",
            "vm_name": "{{user `OVA_VERSION`}}",
            "ssh_pty": "true",
            "ssh_username": "user",
            "ssh_password": "{{user `SSH_PASSWORD`}}",
            "output_directory": "./vmxOutput",
            "headless": "true",
            "shutdown_command": "echo {{user `SSH_PASSWORD`}} | sudo -S shutdown -P now"
        }
    ]

How to solve it?
The $PATH variable:
/home/user/.vscode-server/bin/dc96b837cf6bb4af9cd736aa3af08cf8279f7685/bin/remote-cli:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/VMware/VMware Workstation/bin/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files/1E/Client/Extensibility/NomadBranch:/mnt/c/Program Files/Amazon/AWSCLIV2/:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/windowsUser/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/windowsUser/AppData/Local/Programs/Lens/resources/cli/bin:/mnt/c/Users/windowsUser/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/cmd:/snap/bin

